# Volta ao Inicio da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso ter um ícone fixo na página no canto direito em baixo da tela. Ao clicar nesse ícone 
ele volta para o inicio da página, fazendo o `Scroll` rolar até o topo da página.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Sou iniciante e tenho dificuldade em fazer isso.

Link de um site que faz o mesmo.

http://designgeekz.com/20-best-jquery-plugins-for-2014/

Comment: `<a href="#">link</a>`

Comment: Isso não faz load, só rola (pula) para o topo.

Comment: Ou, via jQuery - `$('html,body').scrollTop(0);`. Em JavaScript puro seria `scroll(0,0);`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda na outra pergunta @Marconi, com as respostas da sua pergunta conseguí resolver meu problema. +1 ;)

Comment: @TiagoP.C tranquilo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## O Botão

**Primeiro vamos criar o botão no aspx**

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="#" runat="server" cssClass="scrollToTop">Topo</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Ou em html:**

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Topo</a>
```

**Aplicando CSS ao botão**

```
.scrollToTop{   
    position:fixed;
    top:75px; 
    right:40px;
    display:none;
}
```

**E por fim, o jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Verifica se a Janela está no topo
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Onde a mágia acontece! rs
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/leodiegoo/Ldy40mca/)**

> Traduzido da página do: [Paul Underwood](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-an-animated-scroll-to-top-with-jquery)

Comment: jQuery para arrastar a página ao topo? Não estamos matando uma mosca com um tiro de canhão?

Comment: @user6492 Se for uma biblioteca que o projeto original já utiliza, não vejo porque não.

Comment: @Marconi, como assim piscando?

Answer (score 10):

O jeito mais fácil é sem script/animação alguma - ao contrário deste link que você deu de exemplo.

Logo após o `<body>`, inclua uma pequena âncora:

```
<body>
    <a id="topo"></a>
    ...
```

Então, inclua a marcação do botão:

```
    <a href="#topo"><div id="botao_topo"><img src="img" /></div></a>
```

Para finalizar, basta aplicar o CSS do botão. Um exemplo está abaixo:

```
#botao_topo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Edit**: preparei um [JSFiddle com pequenas melhorias](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/gsrwue30/) possíveis. Caso queiram aplicá-las, é necessário adicionar um `&nbsp;` à âncora.

Comment: Tranquilo, @Marconi :)
Quanto mais opções de resposta tiver por aqui, melhor, porque a ideia do site é ajudar não só você, como também todos os demais que venham a ver sua pergunta, mais tarde! (Por isso o feedback é bem importante, também!)

Answer (score 3):

Conforme apresentado no link a seguir http://jsfiddle.net/z3w0sbxr/ solução com jQuery, mas como você deseja usar? Com jquery, com html puro sem efeito algum? ... Segue meu exemplo com jQuery.

```
<!-- Parte HTML -->
<div style="">
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
    </div>
    <div id="go-to-top" style="position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0">
        <a href="#">TOP</a>
    </div>

/* Código jQuery */
$('#go-to-top').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
/* Create the div on the main screen and add the elements and show it on the screen */
let divEl = document.createElement('div')
divEl.classList.add('scrollButtton')
divEl.addEventListener('click', topScreen)
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(divEl)

/* Up to top the page */
function topScreen() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

/* Show or hide button on screen */
function scrollButton() {
  if (window.scrollY === 0) {
    /* Hide button */
    document.querySelector('.scrollButtton').style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    /* show button */
    document.querySelector('.scrollButtton').style.display = 'block'
  }
}

/* Monitor page scroll */
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollButton)
```

CSS:

```
.scrollButtton {
  display: none;
}

.scrollButtton:before {
  content: '⬆';
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 40px 'dashicons';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border-radius: 10%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  min-height: 1200px;
}
```

```
Para mais detalhes, pode acessar o repositorio no github:
https://github.com/TayseRosa/toTop/
```

Comment: Mesma observação da outra resposta, isso não ajuda em nada. Pense no seguinte, a pergunta deve ser escrita como um manual técnico onde ensina o leitor a replicar uma condição ou situação de erro. A resposta também ser escrita como um manual técnico onde ensina o leitor a replicar as condições de solução do problema enunciado na pergunta.