# Executar uma ação em Jquery ao clicar em um link

Tags: jquery

Quero que ao clicar em alguns dos links do menu do meu site, execute o scrollTop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-topo a").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (400)
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Acontece que o efeito esta acontecendo antes e logo em seguida muda de página, o que eu quero na verdade é quando clicar em alguns dos links que está no menu, a página carregue e depois então o efeito acontece.

Comment: coloque esta função nas paginas q quer o efeito, e tire o `animate` de dentro do `click`

Comment: O conteúdo é por AJAX ou redireciona mesmo? Se for redirecionado, tem que tirar o evento "click", e rodar quando carrega a página

Comment: é por redirecionamento mesmo, e como eu faço isto Lucas ?
meu conhecimento ainda é limitado em Jquery

Comment: Cara como eu falei, selecione as paginas em q deseja q a animação seja realizada e coloque o seu `animate` dentro do `$(document).ready()` dessa pagina. Assim quando essa pagina carregar irá realizar a animação

Comment: mas nesse caso o efeito irá acontecer duas vezes, quando eu clicar ele vai iniciar e vai ser interrompido, e como estou usando Wordpress por padrão já fica em todas as paginas o mesmo código

Comment: A pagina `menu` nao precisa de nenhuma função. Crie um arquivo `.js` para as paginas q quer esta animação e tire o evento `click`

Comment: Olhe isso aqui.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30703/volta-ao-inicio-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Só coloca esse `animate` para fora do `click` e veja se é isso que vc quer, porque daí ele vai executar quando carregar a página

Comment: Bem fiz tirei evento de clicar com o mouse e coloquei dentro de uma função do wordpress que verifica se esta na página inicial. Com isso qualquer pagina diferente da página inicial vai receber o efeito de deslizar alguns pixels abaixo.
<?php
wp_reset_query();
if (!is_home()) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: (200)
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>    
<?php } else {
    ?>

<?php }
?>