# Voltar ao TOPO jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery

Tenho o script para voltar ao TOPO. Na página inicial do site, ele funciona perfeitamente, porém, nas páginas internas ele não sobe e apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  /* ========================================================================
     Fullscreen burger menu
   ========================================================================== */
  $(".menu-trigger, .mobilenav").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
  });
  $(".menu-trigger, .mobilenav").click(function () {
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  });

  /* ========================================================================
     On click menu item animate to the section
   ========================================================================== */
  $(".mobilenav li, .back-to-top").on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('rel');
    var $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing');
  });
```

O erro remete a seguinte linha:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
```

Onde estaria errado?

Comment: Se fizer `console.log($(target));` o que imprime?

Comment: main.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(anonymous function) @ main.js:26jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.1.js:4641elemData.handle @ jquery-1.11.1.js:4309

Comment: Aparece assim....

Comment: É porque essa variável não tem nada. Coloque a parte relevante do seu HTML

Comment: Hmmmm, pode ser que não esteja achando o destino então, vou tentar aqui!

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta aqui, veja se pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30703/volta-ao-inicio-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Era o destino que estava incorreto, ai coloquei um <topo id="topo"></topo> e funcionou em todas as paginas :) Mas obg mesmo assim.

Comment: @AndréBaill, não invente tags de elementos sem a devida implementação... se o objetivo é apenas marcar uma âncora em seu documento, utilize a tag apropriada para isso: `<a id="topo" href="#topo"></a>`