# Fazer Botão de subir ao inicio aparecer em determinada parte

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de criar um botão para subir ao inicio, mas não gostaria que ele ficasse sempre visível, só quando a página chegar em determinada parte

Comment: Samuel  aqui mesmo no site existem diversas perguntas como a sua, por exemplo esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30703/volta-ao-inicio-da-p%C3%A1gina, dá uma pesquisada. Te adianto já que apenas com **Html** e **Css** não tem como, tem que ser com **Javascript**.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Volta ao Inicio da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30703/volta-ao-inicio-da-p%c3%a1gina)

Comment: @LeAndrade eu respondi mas nem tinha vista a outra... é quase igual mesmo. Votei como Duplicata

Comment: Blza @hugocsl, eu em uma pesquisa rápida encontrei umas 3 parecidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem uma opção feita com jQuery

Quando o btn for `$(this).scrollTop() > 160)` ele aparece, quando for menos de 160 do topo ele esconde. Deixei os comentes no código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
<style>
 html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .go-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4.5rem;
  right: 3rem;
  display: none;
  border: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  z-index: 1100;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div style="height:1500px; width:100px"></div>
   
 <div class="go-top"></div>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   // esconde e mostra o btn
   $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) { // distancia que tem que rolar antes de aparecer
    $('.go-top').fadeIn(250);
   } else {
    $('.go-top').fadeOut(250);
   }
   });
   // manda pro topo
   $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1200);
   });

  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consigo colocar uma imagem de um Seta por exemplo?

Comment: @SamuelNicolau o btn é uma div vc pode colocar o que quiser dentro até um vídeo rss. Mas já editei e fiz uma seta só com css pra vc.

Comment: não está funcionando aqui

Comment: @SamuelNicolau No final da sua página, vc tem que colocar o jQuery `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` e logo depois dessa tab vc abre outra tag `<script> coloca o código </script>` e dentro vc coloca o código que está no início da resposta. Vc tb tem que usar o CSS que usei `.go-top { estilos que estão na resposta }`

Comment: coloquei no final da pagina <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>,....... <script>Código aqui</script>....... e adcionei o CSS .go-top, e nada feito

Comment: @SamuelNicolau cara eu coloquei o código inteiro do documento, o HTML etc.. tudo. Salva isso em um arquivo no seu ai e testa. Tem que funcionar. Se não funcionar é pq tem algo a mais no documento onde vc está tentando colocar esse código que está interferindo no comportamento do btn